# Tachikawa conjecture for commutative algebras proven?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

The Tachikawa conjecture states that $Ext^i(M,M) \neq 0$ for some $i \geq 1$ for every non-projective module $M$ over a selfinjective finite dimensional algebra.
In theorem 4.6. of http://maths.nju.edu.cn/~huangzy/When%20are%20torsionless%20modules%20projective.pdf , the authors prove something (much stronger!) which implies the Tachikawa conjecture in the commutative case, which would be a sensational result in my opinion.

Question:
Is the proof really true/without gaps? I couldnt understand everything and the authors never replied. Of course it might be extremely hard to give counterexamples to theorem 4.6. there but maybe gaps could be pointed out?

Answer (score 7):

On page 2163, the second line, the authors say "therefore ... is exact". I, and some others, believe this is a gap. The authors have been contacted (in 2010) and have not clarified.

Comment: Interesting, did you make it public or what to do now?

Comment: I think one cannot really say that this spot is wrong in the selfinjective case since not even a nonprojective module M with $Ext^{1}(M,M)=0$ is known.

Comment: I didn't say it was wrong. I said I believe it is a gap, that is, not fully justified.